# how to create .exe file for my Qt based app

Tags: qt, executable

i wrote a program in Qt-Creator 1.3.1 and Qt 4.6.2 
and realy dont figure out how to create a simple .exe file for the program i just wrote...
i rather do it with the Qt-Creator if it's possible

Comment: whenever you build the project (ctrl+b), an exe is created either in the Release or in the Debug folders.

Comment: If you have more than one Project opened in Qt- Creator try giving Ctrl+Shift+b or Right click the desired project and click Build Project. Because chances are that exe might be created for the default project which you is not your desired one and you are not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt Creator, when you build (Ctrl+B) your project, it always creates a .exe that is executed when you run the app from Qt Creator (Ctrl+R or the big play button).

If you want to find this .exe, you should look in the folder where your .pro (the project file) is located in the folder debug (or release depending on your build configuration).

Answer (score 0):

@Live is right. See in release or debug dir. But if you move the .exe and want to execute you will get notofications about DLL's that miss. You can find them from yout Qt installation dir. Put next to your exe file all required DLL's and you're done! The DLL files will tell your your exe file while you execute it!

Comment: Can you advise why QT doesn't necessarily put its own QT dlls in the debug or release folder when you build? I have to go and copy them manually from the qt installation directory